# How to create date remainder e-mail?

Tags: rules, emails

HI i have date field  in user profile,after user has been registered based upon current date for every one week i want trigger a mail to user.
example-you are one week old,two week old,like that i want to trigger a mail to user,thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the power of [Rules Module](https://drupal.org/project/rules) and exactly **Rules Scheduler** which is a part of rules.

1. Create a Rule component with the condition "User has role: Role A" and the action "Send email".

> Events: After saving a new user account
>
> Conditions: None
>
> Actions: Schedule component evaluation

In that Action, I chose these options:

```
Component: the component from step 1
Scheduled evaluation date: account:created
Add offset: 7 days
User > Data Selector: account
```

For an in-depth tutorial on how to set this up please [see this blog post on how to use Rules Scheduler to send emails](http://webwash.net/tutorials/how-send-follow-emails-using-rules-scheduler-drupal-7)

You also need to likely have your drupal cron job properly configured as well.

Comment: -i have  followed what you send link,but mail is triggering lately i have internet that to my Cron is running successfully